# Constraint "equal heights" for views of different sizes in iOS?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I saw a lot of similar questions but they are all for situations with equal views.

In my case I have a vertical stack of views:
[image]
And they should **keep proportions simultaneously** on different devices.

Could you advice how to achieve such goal? Xib or programmatically - it makes no odds.

Currently I'm trying to set their sizes manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define equal height constraint, than edit it and set multiplier to e.g. "1:5".

[image: Example]

**Update:**

Choose a vertical stack view, add your 4 views, mark all of them, set the constraint "equal height" and add all 3 constraints:

[image: Step 1]

Now select each constraint and set your multiplier as you like in relation to the first:

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

Define a spacing in stack view settings:

[image: Step 5]

Define StackView border gaps relative to margin or via const value:

[image: Step 6]

You do not need more constraints. Proof by change device and orientation:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. If you add too many constraints into this view its behaviour becomes unpredictable

Comment: I've updated the description with detailed pictures. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The Above answer is fine, but I am adding one more way to use equal heights without using stack view.

add a number of views you want on the main view.

[image]

Give Top, Leading, Trailing Constraints zero to 1st, 2nd, 3rd view and give Leading, Trailing, bottom Constraints zero to the last view.

[image]

[image]

Now ctrl + drag from 1st view to second view and give Equal heights and vertical space. Repeat these steps for 2nd to 3rd and 3rd to 4th view.

[image]

Then select all height constraints one by one and set the multiplier to 1 to get equal height views.

[image]

play with multipliers to change views heights.

Thanks :)

[ios](/questions/tagged/ios)  [autolayout](/questions/tagged/autolayout) [equal-heights](/questions/tagged/equal-heights)